# Landing page bootstrap CSS does not load on all browsers

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I recently made a website,and I am having a lot of trouble with it loading on all browsers. What happens is when you go to the website initially the landing page will either be blank or it will have this weird cast over it, but once you refresh that goes away. I eliminated the issue on some browsers (firefox, safari and brave[this one still errors on my laptop but not my desktop]). The issue over there was that the bootstrap.min.css file was not loading properly, however I got rid of the link to bootstrap.css and used a cdn link for bootstrap.min.css and that seemed to fix the issue. I get a different issue on chrome regarding invalid chrome extensions and I'm not really sure how to fix that. The error says: `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED        chrome-extension://invalid/1`. I tried looking this error up but I was not able to find any relevant info. Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks!

My website is: http://aleksaf.com/

Comment: I think the bootstrap.min.css issue has to do with https vs http. So you would have to get an ssl cert, again I am not sure.

As for the google chrome extension error, I think it would be an error with an extension.

It shouldn't have anything todo with your site, but I could be wrong.

Comment: I see, I wasn't really looking to pay for an ssl cert :( I hope that is not the issue.